# Crosstab Query formula in value

Tags: ms-access

Not sure if this is doable will need your guidance. Below is the SQL for the query and it works fine. The query below takes the work package Current Budget and calculates each members cost as per their share breakdown. The new challenge that I have is to check in the Member Cost formula, if the current budget value entered is a negative amount (this is actually a credit) and this can apply to some Members or all and it should only add that deduction to those members whom it applies to.

I did add a dropdown in the form to select the member that credit will be applicable to and use that field in the query below ?  Need help here in understanding why it does not get the MemberID value from the WPtable?

```
enter code here  SELECT ProjectWPTable.ProjectID, SumProjectMemberShareQRY.DocumentType, ProjectWPTable.WPName, PIFToUDStatusTBL.MemberID, ProjectWPTable.CurrentBudget, PIFToUDStatusTBL.MemberShare, SumProjectMemberShareQRY.SumOfMemberShare, [CurrentBudget]*[MemberShare]/[SumOfMemberShare] AS MemberCredit FROM SumProjectMemberShareQRY LEFT JOIN (PIFToUDStatusTBL LEFT JOIN ProjectWPTable ON PIFToUDStatusTBL.ProjectID = ProjectWPTable.ProjectID) ON SumProjectMemberShareQRY.ProjectID = PIFToUDStatusTBL.ProjectID GROUP BY ProjectWPTable.ProjectID, SumProjectMemberShareQRY.DocumentType, ProjectWPTable.WPName, PIFToUDStatusTBL.MemberID, ProjectWPTable.CurrentBudget, PIFToUDStatusTBL.MemberShare, SumProjectMemberShareQRY.SumOfMemberShare
```

HAVING (((SumProjectMemberShareQRY.DocumentType)=DLookUp("DocumentType]","[ProjectWPTable]")) AND ((ProjectWPTable.WPName)="Credit" Or (ProjectWPTable.WPName)="Work-In-Kind") AND ((PIFToUDStatusTBL.MemberID)=DLookUp("[MemberID]","[ProjectWPTable]")));

![[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaGkf.png][1]
**Sample Data WP Table other info is for the Members**

Thanks
Taruna

Comment: I believe it can be done by you need to including an IIF() condition but it isn't clear to me, without seeing **some sample data**,  how to build the condition(s) into your query

Comment: Please don't use these tiny comments as a way to distribute sample data etc. You can edit your question for that. But perhaps you could read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: **PLEASE** do **not** use these comments for sample data. **EDIT** your question instead.

Comment: @PaulMaxwell I did edit the original post with the snip that has the data.

Comment: "images of data" are not data, they are images. (Just like a photo of a dog is not a dog.)  Twice now you have added text into comments - and that text would make far more sense if formatted - which you can do by editing the question. Please do not use comments as a way to to add sample data. btw: due to company restrictions I cannot see that "snip" as that domain is forbidden to me right now - but I can see the text at stackoverflow

Comment: @PaulMaxwell Apologies for the trouble, I have added the sample data in the original post. Thanks for your time.

Comment: MySQL does not support TRANSFORM. The tag is removed.

Comment: "Do I add a dropdown in the form to select the members" - do you mean a combobox? Only one member could be selected from combobox. Yes, if you want to filter records, can reference combobox as parameter in CROSSTAB query. Will need PARAMETERS clause. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html#Param. Otherwise, no, cannot use 'dropdown' to select multiple members and incorporate in CROSSTAB SQL. That would require a listbox and VBA code using DAO to modify query object. Have a field in Members table to identify those that get credit and use that in calculation.

Comment: @June7 Thanks for your response I added the in the above post the SQL and the issue I have, with the dropdown field value not being pulled in query, Kindly review.

Comment: DLookup() seldom provides desired result without using its WHERE CONDITION argument. Neither of those DLookups specify what record to pull data from. And if you can provide filter criteria in those DLookups, can probably just join to table. You need to provide sample data as text tables so we can better understand db structure and relationships. Or maybe post to a forum that allows attaching files and provide db for analysis.

Comment: @June7 I have added the snip of the data, I was not able to understand how to add data I tried and it was not working so I took a snip.